# Is this function definition related to the Collatz conjecture valid?

Tags: functions, solution-verification, collatz-conjecture

Is the following function definitions related to the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) valid?  Is there a simpler or more standard way to define $C_n(x)$?

Here's what I did:

**Let:**

- $C(x) = \dfrac{3x+1}{2^w}$ where $w$ is the highest power of $2$ that divides $3x+1$

**Goal:**

- Define $C_n(x)$ where:

$$C_n(x) = C_1(C_2(C_3(\dots C_n(x)\dots)))$$

- Define $w_i$ as the highest power of $2$ that divides $C_i(x)$:

**Claim:**

$$C_n(x) = \frac{3^n x + 3^{n-1} + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}3^{n-1-i}2^{\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{i}w_k\right)}}{2^{\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} w_i\right)}}$$

**Argument**:

(1)  Base Case:  $n=2$: $C_2(x) = C(C(x)) = C\left(\dfrac{3x+1}{2^{w_1}}\right) = \dfrac{3\left(\frac{3x+1}{2^{w_1}}\right)+1}{2^{w_2}} = \frac{3^2x + 3 + 2^{w_1}}{2^{w_1 + w_2}}$

(2)  Assume that it is true up to $n$ so that:

$$C_n(x) = \frac{3^n x + 3^{n-1} + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}3^{n-1-i}2^{\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{i}w_k\right)}}{2^{\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} w_i\right)}}$$

(3)  Then:

$$C_{n+1}(x) = C(C_n(x)) = \frac{3\left(\frac{3^n x + 3^{n-1} + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}3^{n-1-i}2^{\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{i}w_k\right)}}{2^{\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} w_i\right)}}\right)+1}{2^{w_{n+1}}} = \frac{3^{n+1} x + 3^{n} + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}3^{n-i}2^{\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{i}w_k\right)}}{2^{\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n+1} w_i\right)}}$$

Comment: ??? Please - what is the question?

Comment: Sorry.  Is the function defined valid?  Is there a simpler or more standarrd definition for a collatz operation applied $n$ ttimes on $x$.?

Comment: Ah, I see. I think a well thought ansatz of this style has been given 1978 by Crandall. I came independently at the same idea to use $C(x)$ in that way, but found that it would serve me and my analyses more to reduce the mass of the symbols (especially in (3)) and to introduce a shorter notation. For me this notation helped extremely to proceed in the formulae of increasing (analytic) depth and still keep overview. You might be interested in that style as developed in http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/aboutloop/collloopintro_main.htm (very old! Naive! but already approaching that style) ...

Comment: Thanks very much!  That's exactly the information I was looking for!  I will check out the reference!  :-)

Comment: ... or this http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz061102.pdf trying to compact everything but should be reworked one day. Perhaps the most economic notation (of that so-called "syracuse"-ansatz, btw) is in my more recent text  http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz_1cycledisproof.pdf . I only lost my energy to really review and reedit my texts...

Comment: My effort is to generalize across the single step operation to $n$ steps.  This is an attempt to get a clearer perspective on the conditions where a cycle would occur.  Example: $C(17) = 13$, $C(13)=5$ so $C(C(17))=5$ so $C_2(17)=5$

Comment: I don't see any error in your arguments; that form of notation is well known and has often been presented and/or discussed. What irritated me is the occurence of $\cdots =C_n(x)=\cdots $ in your argument (3) which I think now is a typo and should have been $\cdots =(3 C_n(x)+1)/2^{w_{n+1}}=\cdots $ . If this reading is correct, then my previous comment is of course superfluous and might be deleted...

Comment: Thanks very much for calling this out.  I will review (3) and fix the mistake once I am clear.

Comment: I assume, in your "Goal"-paragraph, in the first "define" you meant $$ C_n(x) = \underset{n \text{ times}}{\underbrace{C(C(...C(x)...)) }}$$. Otherwise I think it is a very odd functional definition...

Comment: There's a more standard way of expressing this, which is to compile the sequence of divisions by two into a strictly increasing list of powers of two, and it comes up a bit clearer.  Then you get on the left hand side of your equation a power of two which is bigger than all the terms on the right.

Comment: A further link (sorry I forgot it when I read your question first time) is to mathoverflow (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344904/proof-that-3ns-sum-k-0n-1-3n-k-12a-k-2m) I've also answered there, a bit more detailed, perhaps this is as well useful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a more standard way of expressing this, which is to compile the sequence of divisions by two into a strictly increasing list of powers of two, and it comes up a bit clearer.  Then you get on the left hand side of your equation a number whose power of two factor is bigger than that of all the terms on the right.

It's easier to see if you let the powers of $2$ accumulate by using the function $C(x)=3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}$.  Observe that this function commutes with multiplication by $2$ so $C(2x)=2C(x)$.  This means you can keep applying it directly to even numbers too, no need to find the odd number at each composition.

You can see the pattern emerge by manually composing:

$C^3(x)=3(3(3x+2^{k_0})+2^{k_1})+2^{k_2}=3^3x+3^2\cdot2^{k_0}+3\cdot2^{k_1}+2^{k_2}$

Then if you want you can divide by whatever the final power of two is, to yield a 5-rough integer.

If you compose up to $n=$infinitely many times you get a sequence that converges to $0$ in the 2-adic metric space independently of whether the Collatz conjecture is true or not:

$$C^n(x)=3^nx+\sum_{i=0}^n 3^i\cdot2^{k_i}$$ where $2^{k_i}$ is a strictly increasing sequence of powers of $2$.  If I understood your question correctly then this is the greatly-simplified version of your formula.

While $C^{n\to\infty}$ converges to $0$ in the 2-adic space, the Collatz conjecture states that for all positive odd numbers $p$ there is some dyadic fraction $x=\dfrac p{2^r}$ such that for some $n$, $C^n(x)=1$. In fact there are infinitely many such dyadic fractions - if $2^r$ gives a solution $n=n_0$ compositions then every element of the sequence $2^{r+2s}:s\in\Bbb N$ gives a solution too, namely $n=n_0+s$.

Comment: Great answer!  This is exactly what I was looking for!  :-)

Comment: @LarryFreeman you might want to read Terry Tao's 2011 blog post which I think may cover some of this and also some approaches which have given progress but no solution... https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/the-collatz-conjecture-littlewood-offord-theory-and-powers-of-2-and-3/

Comment: Ah. I've studied the function $C(x)=3x+2^{v_{2(x)}}$ for a while allready. One can ask wether this function approaches a pow$2$ number or not. Some new graph teoretic ideas might be worth looking for...